# java access modifiers : no-modifier vs "default"

Tags: java, access-modifiers

I learned that there was a "default" access-modifier , as in "default" being a keyword . However this [oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) doesn't mention any modifier with such a keyword. It only has a *no-modifier* that acts as a default. Has the "default" keyword deprecated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "default" access modifier is when there is no access modifier given (that is, not one of public, private or protected).

`default` the keyword is used in the context of a switch statement. It is the "default action" to take if none of the other cases match.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the two out! for some reason i forgot all about the default in switch !

Answer (score 3):

The default can optionally be used in a switch statement to label a block of statements to be executed if no case matches the specified value. Alternatively, the default keyword can also be used to declare default values in a Java annotation.

Answer (score 1):

```
Access Levels
Modifier    Class       Package     Subclass    World
public      Y           Y           Y           Y
protected   Y           Y           Y           N
no modifier Y           Y           N           N
private     Y           N           N           N
```

There no keyword for default of modifier .That is in different context of switch.

[LINK](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Comment: came to say no keyword for default.

Answer (score 0):

`default` is [keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html) which there for different purpose. Modifiers (`like public, private, protected`) are part of keywords.

Answer (score 0):

You can't mention default as your access modifier. If you don't mention any access modifier (public, protected or private) then compiler consider it as a default access modifier. where if it is a method you can only access within that package only.

Default keyword is used in switch. that keyword doesn't have any relationship with access modifier